# Find the best suggestion on search

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures

I have been thinking about this problem for a while and not sure how to solve it as in best data structure and time complexity for it. This is not homework or anything like that, just casual problem solving, I tried solving it earlier this year, but then I forgot about it.

Imagine you have a website that will make searches best on a keyword you type. You have a data structure that is formed of objects with 2 properties

```
"word": < string value, name of the word >
"popularity": < numerical value, how often the word has been searched >
```

You can pick any data structure you want, and it can be sorted by the highest value first or alphabetically based on "word" values.

for example, consider data values below

```
data = [{
    "word": "ipad"
    "popularity": 100
  },
 {
    "word": "iphone"
    "popularity": 1321
  },
  {
    "word": "ipod"
    "popularity": 22
  }
]
```

if I searched for "ipa", i should get "ipad"

if I searched for "ip", I should get "iphone"

if I searched for "ipod", I should get "ipod"

The algorithm needs to check if there is an exact match for the keyword typed, if found then you return the word; if there isn't an exact match you will select the word with the highest popularity value and you return it.

The way I wanted to resolve this was by using an array of objects to find the best match, but that was O(n) which was not good enough.

I am curious to find out any other ideas, article recommendations to read.

Comment: I think a Trie is the best structure for you.  O(1) lookup after building the tree which can be done in n*(length of words) time.